# How to disable tinymce editor in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce

I have a textarea with id "taClientInformationNotebook" that I initiate as a tinymce editor (4.3.2) on document.ready.

If a certain parameter is passed in the querystring, I want to disable the tinymce editor (making it readonly so to speak). This is achieve by using the following code:

```
  tinyMCE.get('taClientInformationNotebook').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

It works fine in IE but in chrome, it's still possible to edit the contents of the editor. The weird thing in chrome is that I cannot set focus to the editor by clicking on it but what I can do is double click on a word in the editor and marking it. When the word is marked I can click on any letter on the keyboard and the pressed letter replaces the marked word but after that, it's not possible to input more letters until I repeat the process of marking a word by double clicking.

How do I disable the editor in Chrome so that it isn't possible to select a word and replacing it?

Comment: You could initialize tinymce only if this certain parameter is not present in the url, indtead of disabling editor after its initialization. Could that work for you?

Comment: I've tried that also but the result is the same. I'm thinking that this is some tinymce/chrome-"bug"...